# Xcode change Command+click to Control+click

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to change the default shortcut key for open the relevant source code (now it is `Command+click`) to `Control+click` (like other IDE: Eclipse,AndroidStudio)

I have tried to find in `Xcode->Preference->Key Bindings` but can not find the command for change `Command+click`

How can I change it. Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Xcode only , you can't change Command + Click to Control + Click.

If you want to change your MAC Shortcut Key then you can Change it from 
Goto System Preference -> Keyboard -> Modify Keys then update your shortcut key according to your preference.

[image]

Comment: Hey Phan Van Linh, If you got this as your solution please right as correct answer.

Comment: There is a solution for this at https://medium.com/@arasuvel001/new-to-xcode-9-how-to-change-cmd-click-for-jump-to-definition-2dcf2e57ea2d

Answer (score 4):

Go to `Xcode->Preference->Key Bindings`, search for `Jump to Definition`. Update the shortcut key according to your preference.

[image]

Comment: I cannot change the key to `Control+Click`

Comment: I am trying to find the solution for `Click`, but not found yet. Have you.

Answer (score 0):

go to Xcode -> Preferences and select Navigation tab. In the Command-click on Code: change it to Jump to Definition from Selects Code Structure.